# Display not recognised (shows as disconected)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics

I have 2 displays but only 1 of them is being detected by the system, the one that's working is connected via VGA cable to the Motherboard connector and the other is connected via HDMI through an AMD GPU card (Rx 570), running xrandr shows the gpu's HDMI as disconnected, i've tried other linux distros (Debian and POP!_OS) and had the same results, i know the problem is not the monitor or the cable because this setup works on the same machine with windows.

What should i do?

Comment: The drivers in Windows may have the ability to enable multi-monitor / multi-head so it can use both the the iGPU and dGPU simultaneously. The Linux drivers may not have the same feature. Have you tried with only the HDMI one (connected to the dGPU)?

Comment: Yes, but all i get is a black screen (there is no "no signal" message)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for some reason, GRUB (or another bootloader that might be installed) disables the graphics card (not sure if it disables the drivers, the ports, or the card itself).

So to force the graphics card to remain enabled, you need to add `amdgpu.dc=0` to the boot file.

You can do that by running the command:

```
kernelstub -a "amdgpu.dc=0"
```

You'll also have to have a kernel version of 5.15 or newer