# GPU recognizes monitor only before shutting down/rebooting

Tags: display, amd-graphics

I have installed AMD Radeon Pro WX 3100 on a Dell T630 server machine, running on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. I have one monitor connected through VGA to the motherboard and I have another monitor connected through DisplayPort cable to the GPU.

I ran `xrandr` on the terminal and it shows only one monitor:
`VGA-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0` .

I looked into the existing GPUs and the machine does recognize the GPU.

```
lspci | grep VGA
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100]
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2 (rev 01)
```

The monitor connected to the GPU only displays when I am shutting down or rebooting, other than that it goes into 'Power Saving mode'.
I tried the solution poster [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375944/display-not-recognised-shows-as-disconected) but I get errors with the `kernelstub`

How do I use two monitors together?

EDIT_1:

```
sudo lshw -C video

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       logical name: /dev/fb1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:3800-37ff iomemory:3810-380f irq:139 memory:38000000000-380ffffffff memory:38100000000-381001fffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:91d00000-91d3ffff memory:91d60000-91d7ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G200eR2
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=mgag200 latency=0 maxlatency=32 mingnt=16
       resources: irq:17 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:91800000-91803fff memory:91000000-917fffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

EDIT_2:

```
xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94
```

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x41 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x75 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 5 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:AMD Radeon Pro WX3100 @ pci:0000:04:00.0
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo lshw -C video` for us?

Comment: @Redbob, I made the edit to the post with the output.

Comment: Ok. Did you tried to activate the second monitor? (e.g https://linuxhint.com/setup-dual-monitor-on-ubuntu/). If you trried, but didn't get successful, post the output of `xrandr`

Comment: @Redbob I tried but was not successful. As you can see from the output of xrandr, the second monitor is not even showing up.

Comment: I suggest you do this: Disconnect your monitor from DP adapter, open a terminal session, type `tail -f /var/log/syslog`and reconnect it, so you can see what messages the system tells you. Probably there's an issue relating to the DP or with the monitor cable. Times ago we related issues with some kind of DP adapters that doesn't work to certain motherboards